# How to restore separate "Update and Restart" option in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

In earlier versions of Windows, when it was going to install updates on a restart it display a visible indicator on the power button in the start menu and showed separate "update and restart" and "restart" options, allowing you to choose whether you wanted to do a quick restart or let the OS go through the potentially lengthy process of installing updates at this time.

This separate option and clear indicator have been removed, so now hitting restart is a Schröndinger operation that is either a 30s operation or a over hour long procedure without any progress indicator without anything telling you which is which (yes, I know I can find out by going searching whether an update is pending restart but that's way out of the normal path).

Is there any way to restore Windows 11 to have the clear and sensible interface of prior versions?

---

If relevant, I'm currently on version 22H2 of Windows 11 Pro, build 22621.1105. However I don't recall ever seeing the option on Windows 11 since building this computer in late 2022.

Comment: I am stuck on 22H1 but I distinctly remember the option still being seperate - might help to give a exact version.

Comment: 22H2 is different and more combined. You can still schedule Updates (first part) and you can turn ON the notification to be notified of a restart. When a restart is imminent you can pause it.  So from my perspective, nothing wrong with my answer. It just requires paying attention.